# Call 'document / redirect' API inside express controller

Tags: html, express, redirect, controller, multipartform-data

I have `document / redirect` API call as shown below

[image]

It's being called inside HTML Code like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form
      name="autoForm"
      action="http://test/Integration.htm"
      method="post"
    >
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue" />
      <input type="input" name="TEST_VALUE" value="test" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now i want to implement the same logic within express controller. I need to implement a contorller which calls this external API `http://test/Integration.htm`. The flow will be like this:-

Front-end -> Express controller -> Call the `http://test/Integration.htm` -> Redirect the front-end page

I tried to build the below controller inside express

```
export const ssoHandler: any = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const formData = new URLSearchParams();

  const clientCandidateId = req.query.clientCandidateId as string;

  formData.append('TEST_VALUE', clientCandidateId);

  const response = await axios({
    url: `${config.host}`,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    method: 'POST',
    data: formData,
  });

  res.write(response.data)
};
```

But no luck. I tried bulding a custom HTML insisde the controller and sending back to client. But i received `CORS` error. Also i don't believe this is the right approach.

Is there any way to make the same approach using express ?. For security reasons. I can't implement this requirement inside the front-end code. I have to do it inside controller like this.

Answer (score 1):

Basically CORS error refers to cross platform blockage/prevention. You may install cors through cli by running command "npm i cors". and then in your server.js or index.js file write:

`const app=express();  app.use(cors);`

I hope this will help to solve. Thanks & regards.